# Collecting DB Used Space (MB) from SCOM on an Always-On DB

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, availability-groups

My client has asked for database sizing for capacity planning.

I am trying to use System Center Operations Manager (SCOM), however when I get to the Always-On Cluster, it doesn't seem to display the databases which are part of the Availability Group. The counter is named "DB Used Space (MB)"

I am using the SQL Server 2012 Management Pack version 6.6.4.0.

Is this simply a limitation of SCOM, or is something that should be working?

Comment: Are your OpsMgr agents on the SQL Server nodes running either OpsMgr 2007 R2 or OpsMgr 2007 SP1 with the most recent cumulative update for OpsMgr 2007 SP1 applied or OpsMgr 2012?

Comment: OpsMgr2012, not sure on the CU or SP level it has applied. I can confirm there is agents on both nodes.